# CloudFront: Finding the most pulled objects but only by external sources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, watermark

I'm looking to find out the most popular objects (images in my case) pulled by external sources, in order to watermark them. While an automated solution to auto-watermark if pulled by an external source would be ideal, I doubt that's possible, so I'll resume to:

Inside AWS CloudFront, I see "Top referrers", can I get a list of objects being referred by "images.google.de" for instance?

Thanks!

Comment: "*While an automated solution to auto-watermark if pulled by an external source would be ideal, I doubt that's possible"*  It's certainly "possible," depending on your definition of "automated".  CloudFront can cache variants of the same object based on request parameters, and pass those same parameters to your back-end systems, which can react accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to download and analyze the CloudFront logs, which record the [cs(Referer) field](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html#LogFileFormat):

> The name of the domain that originated the request. Common referrers
>   include search engines, other websites that link directly to your
>   objects, and your own website.

You can configure a log aggregator like Loggly to [parse these logs](https://www.loggly.com/docs/aws-cloudfront/) for easy searching.

Comment: I'll try that, realized I didn't log CloudFront, so I'll just select a bucket and wait a few days. It's weird when torrent sites are linking to your images, eats a lot of BW and $$$